# Remove elements of one list from another list using "while"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a simple program which removes elements of one list from another list using `in` method at least two times:

```
def remove(l_list,s_list):
    """Removes items of s_list from l_list and returns the rest"""
    res=[]
    for item in l_list:
        if item not in s_list:
            res.append(item)
    return res
```

I want to replace `if not in s_list` operation by the loop "while" and compare complexity of these functions.

So, I've made the following code(doesn't work):

```
def remove2(l_list,s_list):
    res=[]
    for item in l_list:
        found=False
        i=0
        while len(s_list)>i and not found:
            if item==s_list[i]:
                found=True
                if not found:
                    res.append(item)
            i+=1
    return res
```

Examples:

```
>>> remove2([1,2,3],[1,2])
[3]
>>> remove2([1,2,3],[1])
[2,3]
```

What am I doing wrong? What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if item not in s_list` in your first variation?

Comment: @SimonFromme yes, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append the item after the while loop:

```
def remove2(l_list,s_list):
    res=[]
    for item in l_list:
        found=False
        i=0
        while len(s_list)>i and not found:
            if item==s_list[i]:
                found=True
            i+=1
        if not found:
            res.append(item)

    return res
```

Instead of using the `found` variable you could simplify this if you use `break`:

```
def remove2(l_list,s_list):
    res=[]
    for item in l_list:
        i=0
        while len(s_list)>i:
            if item==s_list[i]:
                break
            i+=1
        else:  
            # this else belongs to the while loop and is executed if and only if
            # the loop wasn't terminated by "break".
            res.append(item)

    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly a logic flaw here:

```
        if item==s_list[i]:
            found=True
            if not found:
                res.append(item)
        i+=1
```

**found** can *never* be False at that inner **if** -- you just set it to **True**!

Also, do you *need* to go through this painstaking check?  You can "easily" :-) do this with a one-line command.  With just list comprehensions:

```
return [item for item in l_list if item not in s_list]
```

You could also turn them into sets, take the difference, and convert back to a list:

```
return list(set(l_list).difference(set(s_list)))
```

Comment: thank you for answer. I can't make it using list comprehensions in this case :( all I need is loop